# How would one address a female priest in the Anglican Community?

Tags: honorifics, gender-positive, forms-of-address

How would one address a female priest in the Anglican Community?

What do you call a female priest in the Episcopal church?

Comment: Stack exchanged forced me to restate the question.  Mea culpa.

Comment: Styles and address are a matter of local etiquette, not the English language per se. The practice in the Republic of Ireland might well be different from that in Australia.

Answer (score 3):

It varies, depending on the priestess's and parishioners' personal preferences (believe it or not, no pun intended).

She may be *referred* *to* as "The Reverend Cassandra Jones," yet, when *addressed directly*, she could be:

***Dear Mother*** Jones

or

***Dear*** Cassandra

[See for yourself!](https://tanenbaum.org/tanenbaum-resources/addressing-religious-leaders/#Anglican)

Comment: I always thought the possessive of *priestess* has three syllables, unlike for goodness’ sake, which has two.

Comment: @tchrist: You're probably right.

Comment: Unlike the Roman Catholic church the Anglican church does not use "Father" as an honorific style, title or designation for priests. Some mainly high church Anglican priests adopt "Father" as a title but it is neither compulsory nor official, merely permitted. Therefore one would only address a female priest as "Mother" if she had adopted it as her title. I don't know any Anglican priests (in the UK) who have done this so I wouldn't think of doing so. In the majority of cases I would address them by their Christian name. Having said that I would usually do that with a male priest  as well.

Comment: @BoldBen: Yes, some Anglican customs are very complicated.

Comment: Or, if you're not yet on Christian name terms, 'Ms Jones'. The American custom of saying 'Reverend Jones' is now widespread in the UK, but is not traditional British usage.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, my dad was an anglican Reader and he always said that 'Reverend' was a description, not a style or title so Anglican priests should be referred to as ' The Reverend Mr, The Reverend Dr' and so on and addressed as Mr, Dr and so on. I assume that would also apply to 'Venerable', 'Right Reverend' and 'Very Reverend' but I've never heard that done.